# Passing id of an element to ajax without using onclick in html

Tags: jquery, ajax, anchor

I had my HTML like this.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="abc"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="bca"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="cab"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="acb"></a></li></ul>
```

when the user clicks on a particular link its id should be passed to an ajax script without using an onclick() function in markup HTML.Can it be achieved using the same anchor elemnt??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 2):

using jquery **[click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** event

```
  $("ul li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
// call your ajax code

    });
```

Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Comment: But how to get id of the anchor??

Answer (score -1):

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e){
var anchorid = $(this).attr('id');
alert(id);
e.preventDefault();
// call your ajax code

});
```

You will get id in anchorid variable.

Comment: give me reason of vote down please

Comment: Not my downvote but you probably got it when you only included a link. Link-only answers are downvoted/flagged by SO users and removed by moderators.